# Python problem during CADInput installation?

Tags: qgis-plugins, installation

I was trying to install CADInput (version 0.60) on 2.4 Chugiak and 2.6 Brighton as well. In both cases I got an error message during installation. For me the following extract of that message might help someone to give me a hint to fix the problem:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xdf in position 27: ordinal not in range(128)

Python-Version: 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

For some reason the installed version of Python does not work properly with the version of CADInput.

I need help to get it run. I'm not a programmer so maybe there's an easy way.